# React - two buttons - a click on one of them opens both

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a React button component with onClick handler and its state - stating whether it was opened on click. If I render two of such components in a wrapper container, and I click on one of them, both buttons update the state. How should I handle the state, so that only one of the buttons updates without using ids?

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const Button = (props) => {
   const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
   const text = open ? 'Open' : 'Closed';
   const toggleButton = () => { setOpen(!open) };
   
   return (
     <button onClick={toggleButton}>{text}</button>
   )
}

// parent component
import React from 'react';
import Button from './Button'

const ButtonsWrapper = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Button />
            <Button />
        </div>
    )
}
```

I also tried reversing the logic and putting the state in a wrapper component, and then passing the onClick handler as a props to a button, but the sitation is the same. They both change the state at the same time when one of them is clicked.

I am using React Hooks.

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem on codesandbox for us?

Comment: Give me some time, please.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this code.  Agree that a fiddle or something would be good.

Comment: I checked again and this code works - https://codepen.io/bakrall/pen/WNooMbR - you are right. Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that you are saying that when you click one button both buttons seems to have their state updated, but you only want the clicked button to update its state.
(i.e. if you click Button A only that button will show 'Open' as its text, Button B will continue to show closed)

If the above is right, *then your code should already do the correct thing. If it doesn't then you might have a bug elsewhere that would cause this.*

If however you want to click one button and BOTH should switch state then you could achieve this by keeping track of the state in the parent component:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const Button = (props) => {
   const text = props.isOpen ? 'Open' : 'Closed';

   const handleClick = () => {
     // do some stuff you want each button to do individually
     .....

     props.onClick()
   }
   
   return (
     <button onClick={handleClick}>{text}</button>
   )
}

// parent component
import React from 'react';
import Button from './Button'

const ButtonsWrapper = () => {
    const [buttonState, setButtonState] = useState(false)
    return (
        <div>
            <Button onClick={() => setButtonState(!buttonState)} isOpen={buttonState} />
            <Button onClick={() => setButtonState(!buttonState)} isOpen={buttonState} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Your first understanding is right - I want to click on one and only this one should update state. You are saying it should work, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help.